'something sounds somewhat off to one's ears" What's the meaning?

'something sounds somewhat off to one's ears"

What's the meaning?

Listeneva: (a) I’ve found somewhere where they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.


Adhemar: I agree with you that (a) sounds the least correct: the double “where” sounds somewhat off to my ears.

source: I've found <somewhere/some place/a place> where

Somewhat odd, strange, or not normal (informal mainly UK use of 'off' as adjective).

One of the definitions of the adjective off provided by Merriam-Webster is “poor, subnormal.” @MichaelHarvey may be right that the usage is more common in the UK, but here’s one American to whom it sounds perfectly idiomatic.

@PaulTanenbaum - The sentence in the OP is pretty UK specific. Being 'on a crowded tube' is something you can only do in London (the Tube is the London Underground railway system). I hate it when people call the trains themselves 'tubes', but then I'm a rail buff. We also say that food that has 'spoiled' is off or _has gone off _. Something rotten in the state of Fridgedom?

Re the OP - I don't agree with Adhemar about the double 'where'. We often use redundant words in informal speech or writing. Guardian opinion piece (advice about making friends after moving to a new place): First, consistently go somewhere where you will see the same people – a gym or a book club, for example

Gee, @MichaelHarvey, I thought everybody knew what the tube was. Nor would I blink if my wife said, “We should dump the milk; it smells off.” Now, I would diagnose a spike in anglophilia if she were to report that the milk had gone off.

@PaulTanenbaum - my cousin's wife went off with the lodger, but that's a different story.

If it's good enough for the New Yorker it's good enough for me. Just when I was feeling discouraged about Austin’s music scene, I talked to Henri Herbert, a blazing young piano player from England [...] He’d tried his luck in London and Paris, but he had to supplement his income by washing dishes. He wanted to be somewhere where he could play every day.

@MichaelHarvey somewhere where is interesting becaue the somewhere in "be somewhere" is an adverb and 'where'(relative adverb) again modifies the adverb: relative clause is an adjectival clause which modifies the antecedent noun.

@PaulTanenbaum - strictly, it's the Tube in writing. 'The tube' is something the nurse has to change every so often.

Ooooh, @MichaelHarvey, yer right I failed to Capitalize Tube.

@PaulTanenbaum - you and a significant percentage of Londoners, I daresay.

It's common in American English  for people to say "I want to eat somewhere they make seafood" (i.e. go to a restaurant that serves seafood). But "....somewhere where they make seafood" is perfectly idiomatic too.

I'm not completely sure which part of "somewhat off to my ears" you're struggling with, so to cover all bases:

"Somewhat" means to some extent; a little.
"Off" in this context means not quite correct; slightly inadequate.

"To my ears", which I think is the main part of your question, is sort of a disclaimer added to show that the opinion is from the speaker's perspective only. The speaker means that he can hear something wrong in the speech, or that it sounds wrong to him personally. Adding this to his statement covers the possibility that he is wrong (somebody else's "ears" might hear it differently). It could also soften the statement slightly to avoid offence. Imagine, for example, if someone you know gave you a violin recital after they recently began learning the instrument, and it's terribly out of tune. You could say "it was out of tune" which could sound a bit harsh, or you could say "it maybe sounded a little bit off to my ears", which softens it by using an adverb of possibility, the phrase "a little bit" to reduce it further, and then "to my ears" to suggest that maybe your hearing is flawed.
Returning to your example - the speaker is commenting on a sentence where someone has used the words "somewhere where". While the two words together might seem repetitive at first glance, the construction is perfectly acceptable and commonly used in English. The two words have their own function, are necessary in the example for clarity, and only sound off because they are so similar. It would be like saying "the constant noise annoys me" and complaining that "noise" and "annoys" sound similar. The speaker perhaps knows this and is acknowledging that it only sounds off to their ears.

somewhat means "in some way, to some extent".  off means "wrong" where the nature of the wrongness is supplied by context:

This translation is off.
These numbers are off.
This milk has gone off.
What was Colonel Mustard doing in the library? Something's off.

So, if something is "somewhat off", it's not quite right.

Those pictures hanging on the wall are somewhat off. They're not quite level. But it's not too noticeable.


Allied soldiers occupying places hitherto held by the Germans had to contend with explosive booby-traps left behind by the enemy. These included bombs wired to pictures of Hitler that would explode if anyone tried to take the picture down, and more fiendish, ones wired to innocuous paintings left slightly aslant that would kill anyone foolish enough to straighten them.
